# Programatically run winforms app crashes on second run

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winforms app that I made to to test some libraries.  I set up this program so all the test settings can be passed in as command line arguments.  I also made a second console app that loads one or more sets of these test settings from files and launches this winforms test app once for each set of settings.  Since each test run hammers the CPU, I have the runs done sequentially as opposed to simultaneously.  I launch the winforms app by calling:

```
WinFormAppNamespace.Program.Main(settings)
```

This works fine the first time, but on the second run, I get an InvaildOperationException from the winform app's Program.cs that says:

> SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first
>   IWin32Window object is created in the application.

Apparently, in calling the static main(...) method to launch the app, some state is created and not disposed of after the run.

I see a few solutions to this:

1) Dispose of the application after the first run - not sure how to do this.  I called a static method and nothing was returned, so I don't think I have access to anything instantiated by running the winforms app.

2) In the Program.cs, put a check around the SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false) call so it only gets run if no windows are created.  Again, I am not sure if I have access to the instance info to check this.

3) Run the app in its own Process.  I was trying to avoid this, as it requires copying additional app.config files to make it work, but I'm starting to think that this is the only options.

Thoughts?

Comment: You are directly calling main?  Create a new instance of the form and show it like any other window.

Comment: Just use a static bool variable that you check before calling the method.  And set to true after calling it.

Comment: After refactoring my parameter handling system, switched it over to create instances of the form like asawyer suggested.  The first run works just fine, but the rest of the runs blow right on through the ShowDialog() and don't give the tests a chance to finish.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault` after a Form has been created and displayed.

This basically means you can't call `Main` directly yourself more than once in a WinForms app.

You'll have to terminate the app before calling `Main` again.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that running a program by calling its static Main(...) method only works once, I have concluded that instantiating the main form and calling ShowDialog() is the way to do.  Just make sure that the program you are running does not terminate by calling Application.Exit() or you may get some unpredictable results.